# How to save a selection of features, temporary in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I want to save a selection of features in QGIS for later, but I don't want to create a new layer or export the selection as shapefile. I just want to save the selection, is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create your selection you may add the expression to the user expression to reselect later

[image]

If you manually select the feature you may create a memory layer with the selected feature (Edit>Copy Features, then Edit>Paste Features As>Temporary Scracht Layer...) you will be able to reselect your feature in the original layer by using select by location (be careful by default memory layer are not saved with the project, you will need to use the Memory Layer Saver plugin if you want to keep it between session)

Comment: Great! Thank you for your solution!